# DatePicker Range Validation | Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms

I'm attempting to implement validation for a non-required Datepicker range input. However, when a user interacts with this input, I need to inform them that they must provide both the start and end dates. Currently, the Datepicker range only accepts the startDate, but I want to avoid this behavior.

Here's the code for creating the form fields:

```
searchForm: UntypedFormGroup;

this.searchForm = this.createSearchForm();

createSearchForm(): UntypedFormGroup {
 return this._formBuilder.group({
  holder: ['', [Validators.minLength(11), Validators.maxLength(14)]],
  startSignatureDate: ['', Validators.required],
  endSignatureDate: ['', Validators.required],
  startContractDueDate: [],
  endContractDueDate: [],
 }, {validators: this.validateDateRange.bind(this)});
}
```

Here's the code for creating the validation function:

```
validateDateRange(control: FormControl): { invalidDateRange: boolean } {
 const startContractDueDate = control.get('startContractDueDate')?.value;
 const endContractDueDate = control.get('endContractDueDate')?.value;

 if ((!startContractDueDate && endContractDueDate) || (startContractDueDate && !endContractDueDate)) {
  return {invalidDateRange: true};
 }

 if (startContractDueDate && endContractDueDate && startContractDueDate >= endContractDueDate) {
 return {invalidDateRange: true};
}

 return null;
}
```

Here's the code for the html code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
 <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="contractDueDate">
   <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="startContractDueDate" />
   <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="endContractDueDate" />
  </mat-date-range-input>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="contractDueDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-date-range-picker #contractDueDate></mat-date-range-picker>
 <mat-error *ngIf="searchFormByParams.hasError('invalidDateRange')">You need to inform both dates.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Note that startContractDueDate, endContractDueDate is not required in the formBuilder.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.